# Compact and affordable solution to quickly test all kinds of SAS hard drives?

Tags: hard-disk, sas

I need to test and wipe a few dozen SAS hard drives.

I'm currently using an [ICY DOCK DuoSwap MB971SP-B](https://www.icydock.com/goods.php?id=141) which is connected to a low profile [Adaptec RAID 3805](https://storage.microsemi.com/en-us/support/raid/sas_raid/sas-3805/) card thanks to a SFF-8087 to 4x SATA cable.

One benefit is the **small size**, as I'm using this hardware in a Small Form Factor computer.

I'm however facing **several issues**:

- some hard drive models are incompatible with the card (e.g. Hitachi Ultrastar HUS156060VLS600) ; altough detected, they cannot be tested.
- 10K and 15K rpm 3.5'' hard drives won't spin in the bay as the circuit board is not designed to deliver enough power.
- the testing process is very slow for several reasons: the BIOS of the PCIe card takes long to load and I have then to manually create an array and add the drive to it.

Using a true tower server would for sure let me test me more drives, but I'm trying to limit the space requirement as well as the required budget.

Any suggestion for a compact configuration accepting a wide range of drive and speeding the testing process?